# ASIFormDataRequest

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I user

```
{
ASIFormDataRequest *rq = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];    
[rq setDelegate:self];
[rq startAsynchronous];
}
```

but it can't access requestFinished or requestFailed function;
why?

Comment: Is there any chance to forgot to add delegate in header file.

Comment: What do you mean "I can't  to access"?
Did "self" conform to protocol ASIHTTPRequestDelegate?